# When a polynomial $f\left(x,d\right)$ of degree=$d$ with complex roots have only real outputs?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

The question by itself is simple: i have a polynomial $f\left(x,d\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{d}\left(x-r_{n}\right)$ where $x$ is real and $r_n$ is complex and i want to know what are the rules to write $r_n$ such that $f\left(x,d\right)$ have a real codomain.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: **Hint :** Begin by thinking of the case where $f$ has degree $2$.

Comment: For any polynomial $f$, $f[\mathbb{R}] \subset \mathbb{R}$ iff all coefficients of $f$ is real iff ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex roots always occur in conjugate pairs in a polynomial with real coefficients.

The way you have constructed your polynomial $f(x,d)$, you can choose arbitrary complex roots $r_0, \dots, r_{d-1}$ such that they don't occur in conjugate pairs. This will cause the coefficients of $f(x,d)$ to be in $\mathbb{C}$ if you choose all complex roots with an imaginary part.

So, your rule is really choose $r_i$ such that they occur in conjugate pairs. BTW, $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$. So, if your degree is odd, you need to choose at least one root from $\mathbb{R}$ after choosing complex conjugate pairs of roots from $\mathbb{C}$.

The simplest example is a quadratic polynomial that doesn't touch the $X$-axis. It has complex roots and they occur in conjugate pairs.